# Why does STRAIGHT_JOIN so drastically improve this query, and what does it mean when it is written after the SELECT keyword?

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following MySql query:

```
select t1.*
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2
on t1.CommonID = t2.CommonID
where t1.FilterID = 1
```

It takes about 30 seconds to run, which was strange, because if I comment out the join or the where clause it takes less than a second:
i.e.

```
select t1.*
from Table1 t1
where t1.FilterID = 1
```

or

```
select t1.*
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2
on t1.CommonID = t2.CommonID
```

each take less than a second.

Then there is the STRAIGHT_JOIN keyword, which I can find one reference of, here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

> STRAIGHT_JOIN is similar to JOIN,
>   except that the left table is always
>   read before the right table. This can
>   be used for those (few) cases for
>   which the join optimizer puts the
>   tables in the wrong order.

What?
I can write:

```
select t1.*
from Table1 t1
STRAIGHT_JOIN  Table2 t2
on t1.CommonID = t2.CommonID
where t1.FilterID = 1
```

and the query executes in less than a second.

Even stranger, I can write:

```
select STRAIGHT_JOIN  t1.*
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2
on t1.CommonID = t2.CommonID
where t1.FilterID = 1
```

and it takes less than a second, and this syntax does not appear to even be legal.

I would guess the second example means that a STRAIGHT_JOIN will be used whenever an INNER JOIN is written, but I can’t find any documentation about it.

What is going on here, and how can the “join optimizer” result in such relatively poor performance?  Should I always use STRAIGHT_JOIN?  How can I tell when to use it or not?

Table1 and Table2 both have integer primary keys; FilterID is a foreign key to another table; the CommonID columns are both foreign keys to a third table.  They both have indexes on them.  The database engine is InnoDB.

Thanks

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> What is going on here, and how can the “join optimizer” result in such relatively poor performance?

`STRAIGHT_JOIN` forces the join order of the tables, so `table1` is scanned in the outer loop and `table2` in the inner loop.

The optimizer is not perfect (though stil quite decent), and the most probable cause is the outdated statistics.

> Should I always use `STRAIGHT_JOIN`

No, only when the optimizer is wrong. This may be if your data distribution is severely skewed or cannot be calculated properly (say, for spatial or fulltext indexes).

> How can I tell when to use it or not?

You should collect the statistics, build the plans for both ways and understand what do these plans mean.

If you see that:

1. The automatically generated plan is not optimal and cannot be improved by the standard ways,
2. The `STRAIGHT_JOIN` version is better, you understand it always will and understand *why* it always will

, then use `STRAIGHT_JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks. any idea what the syntax select STRAIGHT_JOIN  t1.* ... does?

Comment: @zod: you can write a single `STRAIGHT_JOIN` this way instead of individual `STRAIGHT_JOIN` between each pair of tables. It makes the tables to join in the order they are written in the query.

Comment: @Quassnoi, do you mean that having `select STRAIGHT_JOIN` at the start of the query would make straight joins default for all the (possibly more than one) joins in the query?

Comment: @Quassnoi, Or does it only affect the first join in a statement like `select straight_join*from t1 join t2 join t3`?

Comment: @Pacerier: from the docs:  *`STRAIGHT_JOIN` forces the optimizer to join the tables in the order in which they are listed in the `FROM` clause. You can use this to speed up a query if the optimizer joins the tables in nonoptimal order. `STRAIGHT_JOIN` also can be used in the `table_references` list.* http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html

Comment: @Quassnoi, No I mean when we have `t1 join t2 join t3 join t4`, does the straight join only affect `t1 join t2`, or does it also affect the other two joins `t2 join t3` and `t3 join t4`?

Comment: @Pacerier: if you specify `STRAIGHT_JOIN` after `SELECT`, all tables are joined in the order they are listed in the query.

Comment: @Quassnoi, Is that from experience? Because I do not see anywhere in the docs stating such.

Comment: @Pacerier: I just cited an excerpt from the docs, doesn't it say that very thing?

Comment: @Quassnoi, I don't think *"in the order in which they are listed in the `FROM` clause"* is indicative that the effect affects `t1 join t2 join t3 join t4` and not just the first encountered join `t1 join t2`.