# MySQL How to efficiently compare multiple fields between tables?

Tags: mysql

So my expertise is not in MySQL so I wrote this query and it is starting to run increasingly slow as in 5 minutes or so with 100k rows in EquipmentData and 30k or so in EquipmentDataStaging (which to me is very little data):

```
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE dataCompareTemp 
   SELECT eds.eds_id FROM equipmentdatastaging eds
   INNER JOIN equipment e ON e.e_id_string = eds.eds_e_id_string
   INNER JOIN equipmentdata ed ON e.e_id = ed.ed_e_id 
       AND eds.eds_ed_log_time=ed.ed_log_time 
       AND eds.eds_ed_unit_type=ed.ed_unit_type
       AND eds.eds_ed_value = ed.ed_value
```

I am using this query to compare data rows pulled from a clients device to current data sitting within their database. From here I take the temp table and use the ID's off it to make conditional decisions. I have the `e_id_string` indexed and I have `e_id` indexed and everything else is not. I know that it looks stupid that I have to compare all this information, but the clients system is spitting out redundant data and I am using this query to find it. Any type of help on this would be greatly appreciated whether it be a different approach by SQL or MySql Management. I feel like when I do stuff like this in MSSQL it handles the requests much better, but that is probably because I have something set up incorrectly.

Comment: Where do the fields `ed_e_id`, `eds_e_id_string`, etc, come from? It would be clearer to see what's going on here if you used table aliases and explicit references.

Comment: To be fair the reason I named the tables and fields with the conventions I did is so that I do not have to worry about aliasing and so that it is more clear. So for instance eds stands for EquipmentDataStaging, and ed stands for EquipmentData, and E stands for Equipment. Therefore you can extrapolate the joins from the naming convention. I appreciate you taking a look at this for me! I hope I made this clear.

Comment: **tip:** you must index those columns which are using either with `WHERE` or with `ON` condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TIPS

- index all necessary columns which are using with `ON` or `WHERE` condition
  here you need to index `eds_ed_log_time`,`eds_e_id_string`, `eds_ed_unit_type`, `eds_ed_value`,`ed_e_id`,`ed_log_time`,`ed_unit_type`,`ed_value`
- change syntax to `SELECT STRAIGHT JOIN` ... [`see more`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818837/why-does-straight-join-so-drastically-improve-this-query-and-what-does-it-mean) [`reference`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512294/when-to-use-straight-join-with-mysql)

Comment: I re-indexed the tables by dropping and rebuilding the tables. Seems like I am having shotty results. If I get this sorted out by rebuilding the DB with the new indexes which I will be able to do this weekend then I will accept the answer. Also I am definitely not using the straight join correctly either because it is taking way longer when I change the syntax. Thanks!

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the correct answer because it was due to my Indexes. I don't totally understand how MySQL does Indexing but I can assure you if you over index and you have foreign key constraints there can be worse slowing. I wish I received a more thorough answer, but diEcho is right to play around with the Indexes.