# mySQL Query seems to crash server

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a mySQL Query to handle a fairly complicated search in WordPress because I've been struggling to get `wp_query` to do everything I need it to.

However, sometimes the query takes a long time to run (10+ seconds sometimes!) and sometimes it seems to just crash the server (media temple Grid), returning a `internal server error` or an `Error establishing database connection`.

I'm not sure if there's a general syntax error in the query that's causing it to crash or not, but essentially the PHP that generates the query looks like this:

```
<?php

// declare wordpress database global
global $wpdb;

// order by option
$order = $_SESSION['search']['sort-by'];

// users lat, long and distance preferences
$lat = $_SESSION['search']['lat'];
$long = $_SESSION['search']['long'];
$radius = $_SESSION['search']['distance'];

// user search start/end date
$startDate = date('Ymd', strtotime($_SESSION['search']['from']));
$endDate = date('Ymd', strtotime($_SESSION['search']['to']));

// get the main category search ID
$maincat = get_term_by( 'slug', $_SESSION['search']['cat'], 'main-cat');
$maincat = $maincat->term_taxonomy_id;

// grab keywords, replace special chars and spaces
$keywords = $_SESSION['search']['keyword'];
$keywords = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ,]/u','', strip_tags($keywords));
$keywords = str_replace(' ', '', $keywords);

// put keywords into array
$subcatItems = explode(',', $keywords);
$keywords = $subcatItems;

// for each keywords get the sub category id's
$subcats = array();
$count = count($subcatItems) - 2;
for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++) {
    $subcatItems[$i] = get_term_by( 'slug', $subcatItems[$i], 'sub-cat');
    if ($subcatItems[$i] != '') : 
        $subcatItems[$i] = $subcatItems[$i]->term_taxonomy_id;
        array_push($subcats, $subcatItems[$i]);
    endif;
}
if( $subcats != '' ) :
    $subcats = implode(',', $subcats);
endif;



// select
$query = 'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.*, ';


// geo locate
$query .= '( 3959 * acos(
     cos( radians('.$lat.') ) 
     * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
     * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('.$long.') ) 
     + sin( radians('.$lat.') ) 
     * sin( radians( lat ) ) 
     ) ) 
 AS distance , lat AS  latitude , lng AS longitude ';


 // from
 $query .= 'FROM wp_posts ';


 // inner joins
 $query .= 'INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) ';
 if ( $keywords != '' ) :
    $query .= 'INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = tt1.object_id) ';
 endif;
 $query .= 'INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) ';
 $query .= 'INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id) ';

 // if ordered by price, join post meta again
 if( $order == 'mt2.meta_value+0' ) :
     $query .= 'INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id) ';
 endif;

 // if there are keywords 
 if ( $keywords != '' ) :
    $query .= 'INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt3 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt3.post_id) ';
 endif;

 // join table to geo locate
 $query .= 'INNER JOIN lat_lng_post ON wp_posts.ID = lat_lng_post.post_id ';


 // basic filter
 $query .= 'WHERE 1=1 ';
 $query .= 'AND wp_posts.post_type = "event" '; 
 $query .= 'AND wp_posts.post_status = "publish" ';


 // geo filter
 $query .= 'AND lat_lng_post.lat = lat ';
 $query .= 'AND lat_lng_post.lng = lng ';


 // date filter
 $query .= 'AND ( '; 
 $query .= '(wp_postmeta.meta_key LIKE "date_%_start-date" AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) <= "'.$endDate.'") ';
 $query .= 'AND (mt1.meta_key LIKE "date_%_end-date" AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS SIGNED) >= "'.$startDate.'") ';
 $query .= 'AND substr(wp_postmeta.meta_key, 1, 6) = substr(mt1.meta_key, 1, 6)  ';
 $query .= ') ';


 // taxonomies filter
 $query .= 'AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN ('.$maincat.') ) ';

 // if keywords
 if ( $_SESSION['search']['keyword'] != '' ) :
    $query .= 'AND ( ';

    // for each keyword, and a statement to check post title
    $keywordCount = 0;
    foreach ( $keywords as $keyword ) :
        if( $keyword != '' ) :
            if( $keywordCount == 0 ) :
                $query .= '(wp_posts.post_title LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%") ';
            else :
                $query .= 'OR (wp_posts.post_title LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%") ';
            endif;
        endif;
        $keywordCount++;
    endforeach;

    // for each keyword, and a statement to check description
    foreach ( $keywords as $keyword ) :
        if( $keyword != '' ) :
            $query .= 'OR (mt3.meta_key = "description" AND mt3.meta_value LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%") ';
        endif;
    endforeach;

    // for each keyword, and a statement to check sub category taxonomy
    if( $subcats != '' ) :
        $query .= 'OR ( tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN ('.$subcats.') )';
    endif;

    $query .= ') ';
 endif;     


 // if ordered by adult
 if( $order == 'mt2.meta_value+0' ) :
     $query .= 'AND mt2.meta_key = "adult" ';
 endif;

 // grouping and sorting
 $query .= 'GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ';
 $query .= 'HAVING distance <= '.$radius.' ';
 $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$order.' ASC ';
 $query .= 'LIMIT 0, 10';

 $events = $wpdb->get_results( $query, 'OBJECT' ); 

?>
```

If anyone has any ideas, please let me know! And if you need any more information, I'm happy to supply it :)

**EDIT**

The Query seems to struggle a lot more when there are keywords in the search. I'm not sure if there's a better way of writing the logic around :

```
if ( $_SESSION['search']['keyword'] != '' ) :
    $query .= 'AND ( ';

    // for each keyword, and a statement to check post title
    $keywordCount = 0;
    foreach ( $keywords as $keyword ) :
        if( $keyword != '' ) :
            if( $keywordCount == 0 ) :
                $query .= '(wp_posts.post_title LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%") ';
            else :
                $query .= 'OR (wp_posts.post_title LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%") ';
            endif;
        endif;
        $keywordCount++;
    endforeach;

    // for each keyword, and a statement to check description
    foreach ( $keywords as $keyword ) :
        if( $keyword != '' ) :
            $query .= 'OR (mt3.meta_key = "description" AND mt3.meta_value LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%") ';
        endif;
    endforeach;

    // for each keyword, and a statement to check sub category taxonomy
    if( $subcats != '' ) :
        $query .= 'OR ( tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN ('.$subcats.') )';
    endif;

    $query .= ') ';
 endif;
```

**EDIT 2**

Another thought I've just had, would it be quicker to split the query up into separate queries perhaps? So just complete the geo query first, take those post ID's and do the date query, then do the keywords query perhaps? I'm quite new to mySQL so not too sure how to optimise this :/

Comment: well, it is a really heavy query. Maybe moving the distance calculation out of mysql would help.

Comment: Is it possible to move this out of mySQL? All of the latitudes and longitudes it has to check against are stored in the database :/

Comment: Did you have a look at the slow query log of the mysql server? To exclude a general SQL syntax error you could append the generated query to a log file just before the call of `$events = $wpdb->get_results( $query, 'OBJECT' );`. With the help of this log you could try with the help of `EXPLAIN` to optimize the query.

Comment: I haven't actually looked at this, I have tried to add EXPLAIN to the query before but it never runs, I'm not sure if it's something to do with $wpdb? That does give syntax errors for mySQL, so I'd imagine they'd show up there to be honest?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the final conditions to the joins (multiple join conditions).

If you use multiple conditions at joins instead of get a huge set and then put the condition at the end your set will be smaller and your response time may be better.

for instance, you have a final condition:

```
AND wp_posts.post_type = "event"
```

You could put it in the first join

```
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) AND wp_posts.post_type = "event"
INNER JOIN...
```

and so on.

Comment: Hi, just had a go at this, it seemed to help after the initial load of the site, I'm guessing some of it is cached then, but that first load is still quite big and I get 500 errors still :/

Comment: Did you put "..and distance <= $radius" also on the first join?

Comment: Can you check if the time response got actually better? (for instance, putting the command on a phpmyadmin or similar)

Comment: I'll have a look and see if there's a difference in the execution time :)

Comment: Just tried moving conditions one by one, and it seems to increase the execution time by about 1s for each thing I move :/

Comment: so is better or worse with the multiple join conditions?

Comment: also, try with STRAIGHT_JOIN: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818837/why-does-straight-join-so-drastically-improve-this-query-and-what-does-it-mean

Comment: I'd say worse if it's taking longer to run the query overall. I'll have a look at this, thanks.